# Express and Cheerio/JSDOM

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, express, cheerio

I am trying to get Cheerio to work with Express.
I'd like to be able to manipulate the dom from the server, but all I have found is web scraping..

There are some requirements..

At the moment, I am able to run multiple `app.listen(port);` statements, and use multiple servers.

I'm trying to append `<script>alert("test);</script>` to every single page sent by express.

I've created the express server: (Assuming `Path` is a predefined variable)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();    
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        app.use(app.static(Path));
        res.sendFile(Path + "/index.html");
    });
app.listen(Port);
```

Can you guys provide me with a working example to append this to the page. Is there a way to get this to work in real time?

Thanks!

Comment: Cheerio can definitely do that. What have you tried so far and what problems, errors, etc. are you running into?

Comment: Well the problem is I haven't found any sample code... So I wasn't sure where to start..

Comment: Added a simple example. Hopefully that'll get you headed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick/simple example with no error handling:

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile(Path + '/index.html', function(err, data) {               
        var $ = cheerio.load(data);

        $('body').append('<script>alert("test");</script>');

        res.send($.html());
    });
 });

app.listen(Port);
```

I just tested that locally and it worked as expected. Be sure to test `err` inside the `readFile` callback in your real implementation and handle things appropriately if the file isn't found or there's an error reading it.

Comment: Could I do: app.use('/', express.static(Path));  At the top?

Comment: @medemi68: You could use the static module, but I don't think this would automatically run for requests that were handled by static. If you want something *like* static that includes this injection code, you'd probably need to write your own module. Also, you could definitely use a wildcard in the route like `/*.html` to make this run for a range of different URLs. Lots of options.